# What kind of laptop connector is this?

Tags: connector, laptop

I accidentally yanked this cable while working on the LCD, and couldn't identify its function via google lens. It runs next to the LCD cable out of where the lid connects. It's on a hp probook 6450b.

Thanks in advance.
[[image: cable connector][1]]

Comment: Looks a lot like a microphone to me...

Answer (score 3):

That's not a connector. That's the microphone. It's inside a tube of foam to protect it from the sound of bumping the laptop and of typing.

Comment: great to know..